# How to make Android system force LANDSCAPE for all apk?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, apk, landscape

To get this, I've made three kind of modify in android system(v4.04).They are:
1. WindowsManagerService.java, modified the getOrientationFromWindowsLocked();
2. Activity.java, modified the onResume();
3. PhoneWindowManager.java, modified the setInitialDisplaySize();
They all get work, but also with some side effect.
So is there a better modify for this?
Any suggestion will greatly appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Comment: what is the side effect you are facing ?

Comment: for the 1st&3rd modification, it will cause some apk like Chinese Tencent QQ-HDv1.7 down while start, and for the 2nd modification, it can not turn all apk LANDSCAPE, if the apk shows a dialog in the very beginning of start for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me you have to modified your SensorManager class in android. The method provided is onSensorChange(). In this method you can write the code for your requirement i.e for Landscape mode.